# Converting nested Json to CSV using python with unique first column for every row

Tags: json, python-3.x, csv

I have watched many youtube videos and looked at several forums, however, I was unable to find the answer to my question because perhaps my data structure is weird and I am a newbie python user so that will complex things for me.

I have a "data.json" file that looks like this:

## the first few lines of the data as an example:

```
{
    "570": {
        "appid": 570,
        "name": "Dota 2",
        "developer": "Valve",
        "publisher": "Valve",
        "score_rank": 65,
        "positive": 848043,
        "negative": 136246,
        "userscore": 86,
        "owners": "100,000,000 .. 200,000,000",
        "average_forever": 29576,
        "average_2weeks": 1541,
        "median_forever": 523,
        "median_2weeks": 823,
        "price": "0",
        "initialprice": "0",
        "discount": "0"
    },
    "578080": {
        "appid": 578080,
        "name": "PLAYERUNKNOWN'S BATTLEGROUNDS",
        "developer": "PUBG Corporation",
        "publisher": "PUBG Corporation",
        "score_rank": 10,
        "positive": 481531,
        "negative": 468448,
        "userscore": 49,
        "owners": "50,000,000 .. 100,000,000",
        "average_forever": 19962,
        "average_2weeks": 762,
        "median_forever": 10055,
        "median_2weeks": 271,
        "price": "2999",
        "initialprice": "2999",
        "discount": "0"
    }
}
```

## I have tried these things (censored location link for privacy):

1.

```
    import json, csv
    infile = open("C:\Users\....\data.json", "r")
    outfile = open("C:\Users\....\bar.csv", "w")
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    for row in json.loads(infile.read()):
    writer.write(row)
```

2. ```
   import sys
   import pandas as pd
   from pandas import DataFrame
   import json


   data=r'C:\Users\....\data.json'
   print ("This is json data input", data)

   /* Reads and converts json to dict.
   def js_r(data):
      with open(data, encoding='utf-8') as f_in:
          return(json.load(f_in))

   if __name__ == "__main__":
       my_dic_data = js_r(data)
       print("This is my dictionary", my_dic_data)
   keys= my_dic_data.keys()
   print ("The original dict keys",keys)
   /* You assign a new dictionary key- SO_users, and make     dictionary comprehension = { your_key: old_dict[your_key] for `enter code here`your_key in your_keys }
   dict_you_want={'my_items':my_dic_data[0]for key in keys}

   print ("These are the keys to dict_you_want",dict_you_want.keys())


   print ("This is the dictionary of SO_users", dict_you_want)
   df=pd.DataFrame(dict_you_want)
   print ("df:", df)
   /*When .apply(pd.Series) method on items column is applied,     the dictionaries in items column will be used as column headings
   df2=df['my_items'].apply(pd.Series)
   print ("df2",df2)
   df3=pd.concat([df2.drop(['user'],axis=1),df2['user'].apply(pd.Series)],axis=1)
   /*df3=df2['user'].apply(pd.Series)

   print ("df3",df3)
   ```

None of the above link works they produce errors. 
What I wanna do is that I want:

1. open data.json
2. read the following columns from json and put them in data.csv (same location as data.json):
   "appid", "name", "developer", "publisher", "score_rank", "positive", "negative", "userscore", "owners", "average_forever", "average_2weeks", "median_forever", "median_2weeks", "price", "initialprice", "discount"
3. exclude the very first column which is basically the unique identifier for each row and all the aforementioned subattributes are repeated in each unique identified.

Could you please guide me through this?

Comment: if they all have the same keys, [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter) is super helpful. you can just put 'appid' as the first field if that's the unique identifier you want

Comment: @KevinHe Hi Kevin, thank you. However, it is a json file that I want to convert to CSV and I want to remove the unique identifiers instead only collect all the key attributes within them that starts from "appid", "name", etc....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
import json, csv

data = json.load(open('data.json', 'r'))

with open('data.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = [...] # whatever fields in whatever order you want
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)

    writer.writeheader()
    for appid, appinfo in data.items():
        writer.writerow(appinfo)
```

Comment: I received an error: 
98
.
144
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#37>", line 6, in <module>
    writer.writerow(appinfo)
  File "C:\...\Python37-32\lib\csv.py", line 155, in writerow
    return self.writer.writerow(self._dict_to_list(rowdict))
  File "C:\...\Python37-32\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 7-10: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: It starts from 98 and stops at 144 then produces that error.

Comment: oh boi, csv encoding is a mess. can you try it with utf-8 encoding? (see update)

Comment: It worked, thank you so much. I up-voted your answer but it would not show perhaps because I am a new member in the community, but I clicked on "accept answer".